# Javascript Same Output (All Plus) Simple Calculation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML and JavaScript. I want to make a simple calculation where user can input two number and do add, subtract, multiply and divide. After testing many kinds of methods, all of my output is all plus. Can anyone help?

```js
function calculate(){

    var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    
    if (value === Add)
    {
        var answer = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === Subtract)
    {
        var answer = num1 - num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === Multiply)
    {
        var answer = num1 * num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === Divide)
    {
        var answer = num1 / num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <label for "num1">Number 1:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Add">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Subtract">
    </form>

    <form>
    <label for="num2">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="number" id = "num2">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Multiply">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Divide">
    </form>

    <br>

    <form>
    <label id="center" for="answer" style="margin:28px;">Answer:</label>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you defined what `Add`, `Subtract`, etc.. are anywhere? What is `value` in your if-statement?

Comment: Your code results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined @ JS line 6`

Comment: Input tags don't have closing tags, that might give some trouble.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared what `value` is:

```
calculate(this)
```

Add this into HTML when pressing buttons then:

```
function calculate(event)
```

use event to catch witch button is clicked and save its value in variable.

```
var value = event.value;
```

Also add quotes when using `===` . `value === "Add"`

```js
function calculate(event) {

  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);

  console.log(event.value);
  console.log(num1);
  console.log(num2);

  var value = event.value;
  
  if (value === "Add") {
    var answer = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
  } else if (value === "Subtract") {
    var answer = num1 - num2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
  } else if (value === "Multiply") {
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
  } else if (value === "Divide") {
    var answer = num1 / num2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <label for "num1">Number 1:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this);" value="Add">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this);" value="Subtract">
  </form>

  <form>
    <label for="num2">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num2">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this);" value="Multiply">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this);" value="Divide">
  </form>

  <br>

  <form>
    <label id="center" for="answer" style="margin:28px;">Answer:</label>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify, what *value* is, and you must put the *Add*, *Subtract*  etc. in qoutes!

```js
function calculate(value){

    var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    
    if (value === "Add")
    {
        var answer = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === "Subtract")
    {
        var answer = num1 - num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === "Multiply")
    {
        var answer = num1 * num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    
    else if (value === "Divide")
    {
        var answer = num1 / num2;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <label for "num1">Number 1:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this.value);" value="Add">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this.value);" value="Subtract">
    </form>

    <form>
    <label for="num2">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="number" id = "num2">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this.value);" value="Multiply">
    <input id="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this.value);" value="Divide">
    </form>

    <br>

    <form>
    <label id="center" for="answer" style="margin:28px;">Answer:</label>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Add markup -->
    <input type="number" id="num1" />
    <input type="number" id="num2" />
    <button onClick="calculate('add')">Add</button>
    <button onClick="calculate('subtract')">Subtract</button>
    <button onClick="calculate('divide')">Divide</button>
    <button onClick="calculate('multiply')">Multiply</button>
    <p>Result: <span></span></p>

    <script>
      // grab the number inputs from the DOM
      const x = document.getElementById("num1");
      const y = document.getElementById("num2");

      // variables for storing the number values
      let num1;
      let num2;

      // add event listeners to update numbers on change
      x.addEventListener("change", (e) => (num1 = Number(e.target.value)));
      y.addEventListener("change", (e) => (num2 = Number(e.target.value)));

      // show result inside span element
      const result = document.querySelector("span");

      function calculate(op) {
        // return if values are undefined
        if (typeof num1 === "undefined" || typeof num2 === "undefined") {
          return "";
        }
        if (op === "add") {
          return (result.innerText = num1 + num2);
        } else if (op === "subtract") {
          return (result.innerText = num1 - num2);
        } else if (op === "divide") {
          // division by 0 check
          if (num2 === 0) return (result.innerText = "Can't divide by 0");
          return (result.innerText = num1 / num2);
        } else if (op === "multiply") {
          return (result.innerText = num1 * num2);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.